# Can I get the value of decimals in kendonumerictextbox

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

Does anyone knows how to get the value of decimals and format property

```
var mileagerate = $("#mileagerate").kendoNumericTextBox({
        decimals: 2,
        format: "c2",
        min: 0.00,
        step: 0.01
}).data("kendoNumericTextBox");
```

I want to get value 2 and "c2" of decimals and format.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: It would be nice if you can elaborate your requirement.

Comment: the decimals: 2 and format: "c2" , I just want to get the value 2 and "c2" How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get config of any Kendo widgets from `options` property of the object. So in your example you can wite code like it:

```
var options = $("#mileagerate").data'(kendoNumericTextBox').options;
var decimals = options.decimals;
var format = options.format;
```

Be aware that in this case format property has default value ("n") but decimals default value is null so if you did not set it in the widget configuration you may want to read it from the culture value. Then you need to change second line to:

```
var decimals = options.decimals == null ?
    kendo.culture().numberFormat.decimals : options.decimals;
```

Comment: I did it. Thanks very much.